# insert a calendarlist how to get argument calendarid?

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-api, google-calendar-api

in my windows phone application

when i was try use Google Calendar API insert a CalendarList as Fllow link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert

about reqeust it was need a calendar id. when i insert some format string . it was tip some reaource can't be found.

how to define a google calendar id in my windows phone application? or

is there have some interface automatically generated?

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar ID refers to the particular calendar you are trying to access. For any primary calendar, it will be your email address.  For secondary calendar, you can find the Calendar ID in the Calendar setting.  Under Calendar details, you will see a the Calendar address where the Calendar ID is located.